# Dual Sim: Surfing while receiving an incoming call

Tags: mobile-data, dual-sim

I am planning to buy a dual sim mobile phone. One sim for cheap surfing and one sim for for calling. But i am unsure about some techniques of the technology.

If am surfing with sim2. Can the sim1 card receive incoming calls? Or is the sim1 blocked, as long as i am surfing?

best regards 
zesman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dual sim smartphone is the same as a normal one except for:

-You can't use a sim while the other one is calling (it goes to airplane mode)

-You can use one mobile data sim at time, but they'll both receive incoming calls

So if I understood correctly your question, yes, you can